# Secure Privileged Service <=> Userspace named pipe WCF-Connection

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, named-pipes, privileges

I have something like this:
[image: Architecture]

*(There's a **Client**, which needs to launch a third-party .exe with Admin-Privileges with some custom parameters. To not constantly annoy the user with UAC-Dialogs, I made a **Service** running with SYSTEM Privileges. The Client and Service communicate via **WCF and `NetNamedPipeBinding`**.)*

---

That works fine, I'm only worried about the security. The risk is that I do not control the third party .exe, so I dont know what some undocumented parameters might do. *(Maybe it allows launching some process, which would allow privilege escalation to SYSTEM rights from userspace)*

I do not see anything that authenticates the Client to the Server as being the valid client. Given that Named Pipes are a known security risk/problem (saw  http://www.blakewatts.com/namedpipepaper.html / https://hackinparis.com/data/slides/2017/2017_Cohen_Gil_The_forgotten_interface_Windows_named_pipes.pdf ), I was looking for a best practice/security checklist, but found none.

---

So the question is basically: **How do I make sure that only my client (not other unelevated programs) can connect to the privileged service?** And how do I do that while using WCF?

What I've thought of so far:
Both `Service.exe` and `Client.exe` will be in `C:\Program Files\<some name>`. Other unelevated programs can't write to this path, so maybe let the Client write the arguments in some file there and let the service read it? Can a similar method be used for authenticating the whole WCF connection?

Comment: this is impossible. you say can call `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId` and by given *ClientProcessId* check that exactly from process created from *<path>client.exe* was request. but what if somebody inject self code in *client.exe* and/or simply use it as container for self code ? how minimum with this api you can check that request is from local system, not remote

Comment: You cannot possibly hope to secure a system you've already decided to not secure. If you run arbitrary code under the SYSTEM account, you've essentially given up the system.

Comment: @RbMm thanks! Wouldn't injecting require admin privileges? Else the whole `Program Files` write-protection would be essentially useless.

Comment: @IInspectable Agree! Altough its untrusted not arbitrary code, and you can still make it better or worse.

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls injecting to process not require admin basically. it require ability open process (so enough run at the same security level with process) or even more simply 0 exec new process based on your exe yourself and do inject. so not need admi

Comment: however you how minimum filter remote pipes connect, the pid in this case will be *0xfeff* (not valid process pid)